# What is the political situation of The Force Awakens?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

I hate that I have to say this, but Abrams is making me wish for more politics in the new Star Wars. Mostly concerning the interactions between the two main factions:

> So we have the First Order (referred to henceforth as the First Rodeo) and the Resistance. It seems to me like the First Rodeo is descended from the Empire, or at least its military, though for much of the movie they're attacking rather than defending, which makes me think they started from a much lower position. On the other side of the spectrum, there's the Resistance (referred to henceforth as Revengeance), who always seems to be defending, or at least reacting to the First Rodeo. Plus, they seem connected to the Republic, which I assume is an offshoot of the Empire's government, or of the government of the prequels' Republic. So it makes no sense to me why the Revengeance has such a name, since they seem to be operating in a similar capacity to the GAR or the Imperial Stormtroopers.

So, I'm mostly wondering what things are like in other parts of the galaxy. Is First Rodeo actually winning everywhere else, or is the Revengeance actually smaller than they seem? Do these names make any sense? Are there really any answers at all?

Comment: The first order is **DEFINITELY** descended from the Empire; their stormtroopers' aim is quite possibly worse than that of the originals!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the start of this is explained in the [Aftermath](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Aftermath) and [Lost Stars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lost_Stars) books.

> After the [battle of Jakku](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Jakku) a treaty was signed carving up the galaxy. The new republic with some systems and the vestige of the empire with others.

In the Force awakens it seems

> Some of these vestiges formed into the resurgent new order. It seems but is not totally clear yet, that the rebellion is a separate entity fighting against the first order. In a speech made by General Hux he accuses the Republic of supporting the Rebellion, as in a proxy war.
>  There is very little about the new republic in TFA so we will have to wait to find out what is happening in more detail.

It is also apparent by the end of the force awakens that

> The new republic's home system, including it's fleet are lost. The Resistance have lost half their fleet of X-Wings.

So what the political situation after the film is could be anyone's guess.

Comment: this is about the only thing that makes sense, otherwise there's no explanation for how the First Order has any authority at all, or why there needs to be a Resistance to them.

Comment: could you cite which books you mean there? (in the "aftermath" I didn't see anything that indicated the thing you noted int he first spoiler tag)

Comment: I have linked to the books, I don't know precisely what is in each book. Would love someone who has read to edit.

Comment: If there is a territorial division, that would explain it. Presumably, the Republic and Empire are nominally at peace; but the Republic is covertly supporting the Resistance, which is is fighting the Empire on its own territory. It would be like many civil wars in our own world, where one side has weapons and "advisors" from outside the country.

Comment: The Battle of Jakku was in Lost Stars - http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Jakku